# Read NSURLSession credentials on rails server

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, authentication, credentials

I have an iOS client and a RoR backend. didReceiveChallenge takes care of passing credentials when getting an auth challenge from server. Using Charles, i can see the credentials being passed along with the subsequent request, but i am not able to access it in the server-side, as they are not in the headers or in the params hash. What am i missing?

screenshot of Charles: http://s29.postimg.org/iqch2p0pz/Sk_rmbillede_2014_01_10_kl_18_56_49.png

Below is my code:

iOS

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didReceiveChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential *))completionHandler {

NSString *user = @"my@email.com";
NSString *password = @"secretpass";

NSURLCredential *secretHandshake = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:user password:password persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];

// use block
completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential,secretHandshake);
}
```

Rails

```
class Api::V1::SessionsController < Milia::SessionsController

include Devise::Controllers::Helpers

skip_before_filter :require_no_authentication, :only => [:create ]

respond_to :json

def create
    email = params[:user_id]
    password = params[:password]

    puts 'create session'
    puts params[:authentication]
    #puts request.headers.inspect
    puts 'create session'

    if request.format != :json
        self.headers["WWW-Authenticate"] = %(Basic realm="Application") 
        render :status=>406, :json=>{:message=>"The request must be json"}
        return
    end

    if email.nil? or password.nil?
        self.headers["WWW-Authenticate"] = %(Basic realm="Application") 
        render :status=>401, :json=>{:message=>"The request must contain the user email and password."}
        return
    end

    @user=User.find_by_email(email.downcase)

    if @user.nil?
        logger.info("User #{email} failed signin, user cannot be found.")
        self.headers["WWW-Authenticate"] = %(Basic realm="Application")  
        render :status=>401, :json=>{:message=>"Invalid email or passoword."}
        return
    end

    # http://rdoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/TokenAuthenticatable
    @user.ensure_authentication_token!

    if not @user.valid_password?(password)
        logger.info("User #{email} failed signin, password #{password} is invalid")
        self.headers["WWW-Authenticate"] = %(Basic realm="Application")
        render :status=>401, :json=>{:message=>"Invalid email or password."}
    else
        render :status=>200, :json=>{:token=>@user.authentication_token}
    end
end
...
```

So my question is, how do i access the user and password credentials from didReceiveChallenge on the server-side?